# How to fade in a div on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hover on an image, and have a div with text in it to fade in. Simple.

Sidenote: I want it to be style-able by CSS. (Kind of a given.) Also, I tried using some examples but I am in a hurry so please and thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

If your using jQuery, Something like:

```
$('element').hover(function()
{
    $('div').animate({ 'opacity': 1 });
});
```

Comment: If you could, will you provide the html too, if its not to much. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="hover">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="google" />
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
    This text will Fade In and Out.
</div>​

$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $("div.hover").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.fade").fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.fade").fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});​
```

[Sample code here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/1/)

By the way, how do you want it to be CSS stylable?

Comment: I need to be able to style the div but thats easy.

Comment: nice example +1 from me but how can div stay visible when mouse is over faded div? If faded div contain some links it's not useful because it goes off when mouse is out of parent div?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/2WYtS/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods.
[Link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/fadein-fadeout-fade-out-effect-in-html-text-div-using-jquery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS You can change fade out using opacity

try This

```
.box{
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#000;
}

.box:hover{
        opacity: 0.7;
}
```