# Fade in a non-text element during mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fade in an element on my page that is some text formatted with CSS. I can get a plain text element to fade in using `element.fadeIn()`. But that doesn't work with my document's current element. The `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events are correctly just showing and hiding the element with no fade. I'm trying to get it to fade in (and eventually fade out) with the mouse events.

The first part of the `<body>`:

```
<body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="title">Application</h1>
            <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu" >
            <li onMouseOver="change_it('sub2');" onMouseOut="change_back('sub2');">
                    <a href="../app.exe">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">APPName</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Click to Install</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
```

Function for trying to fade in the text:

```
function change_it(id)
{
   setVisibility(id, 'inline');
   //id.FadeIn("slow");
   // $('div.detail').fadeIn('fast');

}
```

Function to setting the visibility:

```
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
```

The "sub2" element:

```
<div class ="detail" id="sub2">
<p><b>Welcome my application!</b></p>
<p>Here is a bunch of text I want to fade in during a mouse over another element!
</p>
</div>
```

From the CSS file:

```
.detail{ 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: 35%; 
width: 650px; 
height: 300px;
Line-height: 1.4em;
color : white; 
}
```

Can someone spot the problem or suggest what I need to do to fade in the "sub2" element during that mouse over action?

Comment: The fadeIn / fadeOut jQuery functions are very limited on what kinds of elements they will work on.

Comment: You want to fade in specific text or any element?  Do you want the element that is *not* visible to take up space, or to fade in and take up space at the same time (`visibility:hidden` vs `display:none`).

Comment: What is the method `setVisibility`?

Comment: I'm fine with not using the jQuery fading functions if it will accomplish the end goal. 

It is also okay if the element consumes space. There are actually multiple elements containing formatted text in that area, they are going to be faded based on different mouse hovering regions. 

Sorry, I added the `setVisibility` function.

Comment: You could use jQuery animate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878027/how-to-fade-in-a-div-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't answer my question about display vs visibility, I'll assume you want it to take up space (example):

css:

```
.fade-in
{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;    
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.fadeIn').on('click', function()
  {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).toggleClass('fade');
  });
});
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="fadeIn" data-target="#theId">Click me!</a>
<div id="theId" class="fade-in">You clicked on Click me!</div>
<div>Hi!</div>
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1e2t5s2y/1/)